# Code after AWT object creation seemingly not executed

Tags: java, c++, linker, java-native-interface, awt

Test.java

```
import java.awt.Frame;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      System.out.println("test main");
      Frame t = new Frame();
      System.out.println("test main2");
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("Catch");
    }
    finally {
      System.out.println("Finally");
    }
  }
}
```

test.cc

```
JNIEnv *_VMEnvironment;
JavaVM *_VM;
jclass _JavaClass;

void init()
{
  const int tCount = 1;
  JavaVMInitArgs tArgs;
  JavaVMOption tOptions[tCount];

  tArgs.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
  tArgs.nOptions = tCount;
  std::string tPath = "-Djava.library.path=/usr/lib";

  tOptions[0].optionString = const_cast<char*>(tPath.c_str());
  tArgs.options = tOptions;
  tArgs.ignoreUnrecognized = JNI_FALSE;

  JNI_CreateJavaVM(&_VM, (void**)&_VMEnvironment, &tArgs);
}

void start()
{
  jmethodID tMainMethod;
  _JavaClass = _VMEnvironment->FindClass("Test");
  tMainMethod = _VMEnvironment->GetStaticMethodID(
    _JavaClass, "main", "([Ljava/lang/String;)V");
  _VMEnvironment->CallStaticVoidMethod(_JavaClass, tMainMethod, nullptr);

  std::cout << "Done" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  init();
  start();
  return 0;
}
```

If I link against `libverify, libjava, libjvm` I get the following output:

```
test main  
test main2  
Finally  
Done
```

However if I also link against `libjawt, libmawt, libawt` I get the following output:

```
test main  
Finally  
Done
```

I'm very puzzled why the second println (seemingly) isn't getting executed. I tried creating other object types instead of the Frame and didn't see the issue occur. Likewise I tried various awt object types and always saw the same result. For reference I'm running 64bit centos with java 1.7.0_51.

Comment: Try catching Error, or Throwable, rather than just Exception.

Comment: Ah, that was it. It was throwing an unsatisfied link error. Thanks.